# Where should I insert try, except, finally in my code?

Tags: python

Where should I insert my try, except, finally to capture errors?

This is a program to add/reject element in the list

```
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

print("Initial elements of UniqueList:", myUniqueList)
print("Initial elements of LeftOvers:", myLeftovers)

myUniqueList.append(2)
myUniqueList.append(10)
myUniqueList.append(25)
myUniqueList.append(61)
print("Current elements in the list:", myUniqueList)
```

Function to add element to UniqueList

```
def AddToList(x):
    if x not in myUniqueList:        
        myUniqueList.append(x)
        print("Added Value:")
        print(myUniqueList)
        return True
    else:
        AddToLeftOver(x)
        return False
```

Function to add element to LeftOver

```
def AddToLeftOver(x):
    myLeftovers.append(x)
    print("LeftOver value:")
    print(myLeftovers)
```

Add element to list

```
x = int(input("Enter value:"))
print(AddToList(x))
```

Comment: The first thing you can "try" is to remove Pls help from your title. No one likes a plzbro

Comment: remove unnecessary my-prefix and write variable names and functions all in small caps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add try, except without problem, like this:

```
def AddToList(x):
    if x not in myUniqueList:
        myUniqueList.append(x)
        print("Added Value:" + str(x))
        return True
    else:
        AddToLeftOver(x)
        return False

def AddToLeftOver(x):
    myLeftovers.append(x)
    print("LeftOver value:" + str(x))

myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

print("Initial elements of UniqueList:", myUniqueList)
print("Initial elements of LeftOvers:", myLeftovers)

myUniqueList.append(2)
myUniqueList.append(10)
myUniqueList.append(25)
myUniqueList.append(61)
print("Current elements in the list:", myUniqueList)

x = int(input("Enter value:"))
try:
    AddToList(x)
except:
    AddToLeftOver(x)

print("myUniqueList: " + str(myUniqueList))
print("myLeftovers: " + str(myLeftovers))
```

I couldn't add finally because there are only 2 options True or False.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look, at which places exceptions can occure.

In `add_to_list` and `add_to_leftover` the only methods used are `in` and `append`. Both don't raise exception, so no need for try-except:

```
def add_to_list(unique_list, leftover, element):
    if element not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(element)
        print("Added Value:")
        print(unique_list)
        return True
    else:
        add_to_leftover(leftover, element)
        return False
    
def add_to_leftover(leftover, element):
    leftover.append(element)
    print("LeftOver value:")
    print(leftover)
```

In the main program, you ask for user input and convert it to int:

```
x = int(input("Enter value:"))
```

At this place, the input is possibly not convertible to int, so a exception is raised:

```
unique_list = [2, 10, 25, 61]
leftover = []
try:
    x = int(input("Enter value:"))
except ValueError:
    do_what_ever_is_need_in_this_case()
finally:
    print(add_to_list(unique_list, leftover, x)
```